# adding css to actionlink with area defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink

I have an `@Html.ActionLink()` as such

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ändra lösenord!!", "ChangePassword", "Manage", new { area = "Account" }, new { @class = "settingsMenu" })
```

But it wont take my class, how can I add a css-class to my `ActionLink` that has an `area` defined already?

On another link (without area it works fine)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Skapa konto", "Register", "", new { @class = "loginfront" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change your code as follow:
**Edited:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ändra lösenord!!", "ChangePassword", new { area = "Account", controller = "Manage" }, new { @class = "settingsMenu" })
```

Comment: When I do it only appends the class name to the url, I get the following html output: <a href="/Account/Manage/ChangePassword?class=settingsMenu">Byt lösenord</a>

Comment: @darrrrUC, I edited answer, it must resolved your problem.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I allso added and answer, your code above is correct but I allso had conflicting css behind the scene messing things up further :)

Answer (score 0):

It was a conflict of css, added !important to my "settingsMenu" class and now it works.